# How to optimize this progression algorithm?

Tags: c, optimization

I have this quadratic algorithm and would like to reduce its asymptotic behavior. The input is an

```
n > 0
```

corresponding to the progression cardinality, while the output is the sum and subtraction of the terms.

Any thoughts?

```
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ ){
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++ ){  
    if (i == j) {
      sum = sum -1;
    } else {
       sum = sum + 1;
    }        
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to tell us what it is *supposed* to do so we don't try reverse engineer it? From the first glance it looks like it has a simple analytical solution in O(1).

Comment: How often do you expect `i==j` to be true? How often *not* true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the desired value can be calculated directly as follows.

```
int sum = n * n - 2 * n;
```

There are `n * n` iterations of the inner loop's body. For most cases, sum is increased. For `n` cases (where the pair `(i, j)` lies on the *diagonal*) the sum is not only not contributed to, but decreased.

Comment: Got it! But is there any optimization that reduces, but does not eliminate, the quadratic behavior?

Comment: @Jacobi `n*n` is kind of the very definition of quadratic?